# Is there an ActionScript library for Twofish Encryption/decryption

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, cryptography

Do you know a library in ActionScript 3 that can encrypt and decrypt using the TwoFish algorithm?

I have been using [as3crypto](http://code.google.com/p/as3crypto/) for other cryptographic algorithms, but unfortunately, it doesn't seems to handle Twofish...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I do not believe there is. I did a light search a little while back looking for such a library but there was not much. What I had planned on doing and what seems to be your best option, is to possibly roll your own? There are plenty of examples of implementation of the cipher that you can find through Google. I would go by a C# example and convert it over. Let us know if you do that so others can use it!

Comment: I am actually planning to code my own since I couldn't find anything either, will for sure post an update here when I find the time to start coding.

Answer (score 1):

Twofish was Bruce Schneier's entry into the competition that produced AES. It was judged as inferior to an entry named Rijndael, which was what became AES.

However, there is a third-party encryption library for ActionScript that includes AES.

http://code.google.com/p/as3crypto/

Comment: yep this is the library I mentioned in the post, it's very good, but doesn't feature twofish, if I ever find time to code my own twofish, I'll certainly consider to contribute it to the library.